# Does there exist a hash function which has a fixed point?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Does there exist a hash function $h$ and an input $x$ such that $h(x) = x$? I believe this is a special case of collision-resistance. I imagine such a case is guaranteed not to be possible (otherwise such a hash function wouldn't always be guaranteed to be useful), but how is such a case proven to not be possible?